# Trapezoidal and Simpson's rule for a function

Tags: calculus, integration

Approximate $\int _0^1\: \sqrt{2-x^2}dx$ using the trapezoidal and simpson's rule for 4 intervals.

Now I can determine the simpson rule is
$$\frac{h}{3} \big(f(x_0) + 4f(x_1) + 2f(x_2) + 4f(x_3) + f(x_4) \big)$$
and the trapezoidal rule is

$$\frac{h}{2} \big(f(x_0) + 2f(x_1) + 2f(x_2) + 2f(x_3) + f(x_4) \big)$$

and $h= \frac{b-a}{n}$ which I assume is $\frac{1-0}{4}$

But what I don't understand is in knowing this how you add it all together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the Simpson rule as an example.

Pick the equally-spaced points at 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75 and 1. Let $f(x) = \sqrt{2-x^2}$. Then, the Simpson expression becomes,

$$\frac{1}{12}(\sqrt 2 + 4 \sqrt{ 2-0.25^2} +2\sqrt{2-0.5^2}+4\sqrt{2-0.75^2}+1)$$
$$= \frac {1}{12}(\sqrt 2 + \sqrt{31} + \sqrt 7 + \sqrt{23} +1) = 1.2853$$

Compared with the exact integral result

$$\int_0^1\sqrt{2-x^2}= \frac{2+\pi}{4}=1.2854$$

the 4-point Simpson numerical integration is very accurate.

The similar procedure can be carried out for the Trapezoidal rule.

Comment: I see, but where do the values for the equally-spaced points come from?

Comment: @DuncanK3 - since you decide to use 4 points within the integration range (0,1), you divide the range by 4 to get $(1-0)/4=0.25$. The values of those equally spaced points are just multiples of 0.25

Comment: Ah ok that was the piece of the puzzle I was missing!

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually find the values of $x_0$, $x_1$, $\ldots$, $x_4$ and then plug them into $f$ so that you get the values of $f(x_0)$, $f(x_1)$, $\ldots$, $f(x_4)$. Then you just plug them in and evaluate.

For example, $x_0=0$ and $x_1=0+\frac{1}{4}$, so $f(x_0)=\sqrt{2-0^2}=\sqrt{2}$ and $f(x_1)=\sqrt{2-\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}=\frac{\sqrt{31}}{4}$. Then plug those in. For example, with Simpson, you get $$\frac{h}{3}\left(0+4\cdot \frac{\sqrt{31}}{4} +2f(x_2)+4f(x_3)+f(x_4)\right)$$
Now do it for $x_2$, $x_3$, and $x_4$, and you'll have done the Simpson's Rule part. The Trapezoid part is similar.

Comment: I did try and plug in using the formula but how did you get (x1) = 1/4?

Comment: @DuncanK3 Start with $x_0$ as the lower number in the interval ($0$ in this case) and then add $h$ each time to get $x_1,x_2,x_3$ etc. So we have $x_1=x_0+h=0+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{4}$, then $x_2=x_1+h=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{2}$, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use the formula correctly this time!